# Error C2059 while declaring macro that uses SAL to define a type (?)

Tags: c, visual-studio, sal

I inherited some code, the code in question builds (for someone I have no access to, in a way older version of VS.) I am attempting to migrate it to VS2019.

One error I keep getting is:
Error   C2059   syntax error: '[' 
At: \CodeAnalysis\SourceAnnotations.h   290

The use in question is for this:

```
#include <CodeAnalysis/SourceAnnotations.h>
#define F_PRINT [SA_FormatString(Style="printf")] const char *  
int x_sprintf(char *buffer, size_t buf_size, F_PRINT format, ...);
```

if I modify x_sprintf as follows, it works (and by work, I mean that one line's error goes away.)

```
int x_sprintf(char *buffer, size_t buf_size, [SA_FormatString(Style="printf")] const char * format, ...);
```

One problem is, this F_PRINT is used all over, so I rather not go changing it all over the place (at least not yet.) Plus, the fact that I know this built at some point (no changes been done) means the error most be with my environment. Maybe I am missing some compiler command flags?

Maybe some SAL formatting was depreciated, at least if used on macros? If so how should I reformat this?